# How can I install a .ISO in a windows environment over Group Policy using Windows Server 2013

Tags: windows-7, windows

I want to install the **Office Multilanguage Pack 2013 with SP1 64bit MultiLanguage Proofing Tools** but it is only supplied as a .ISO

I think I can only install the Programs over Microsoft Group Policy when they are provided in .msi

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you checked what is inside the .ISO file? You can open it with 7zip or WinRAR for example. It is just an archive with some other shenanigans. ;-)

Comment: Download and extract the ISO to a network location and script the install via GPO... fairly trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You can mount the ISO by following these [directions](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/mount-an-iso-image-in-windows-vista/) with Virtual Clone Drive.  Then the ISO will appear as a DVD or CD.  You can then use the contents as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Use a program to extract the files in the ISO file. I like using 7Zip, but others have pointed out several other tools that would work as well. Once you've done that Microsoft has provided directions to install various Office components via GPO, as it's not deployed like most MSI files are (you have to run a script and install it that way). See directions for details: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602181.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can also install from iso. Just try **Winrar** or **PowerISO** or any other program and open the contents of iso file. You'll find .msi file inside iso.